# Is there a way to add a second custom field in google people api when creating a person?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

I am importing google contacts from a csv file in a specific manner, in the file I have 2 custom fields that need to be added to every contact when they are imported. I have added the first custom field but have no idea how to add a second one programatically. It seems possible as you can add a second custom field from the contact page. Here is the code to add one custom field to the contact:

```
$opened_file=fopen("export_test.csv", "r");
while(($data = fgetcsv($opened_file, 1000,",")) !== FALSE)
{
  $contacts[] = $data;
}


$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();
$custom_field = new Google_Service_PeopleService_UserDefined();

for($i = 1; $i < count($contacts); $i++)
{
  $custom_field->setKey($contacts[$i][50]);
  $custom_field->setValue($contacts[$i][51]);

  $person->setUserDefined($custom_field);
}
```

I have tried making a new user defined object, setting the key and value and attaching it to the person but this just overwrites the first custom field. I have also looked this issue up but turned up with nothing. Is it possible to add a second custom field programatically?

Answer (score 0):

UserDefined is a **list** in the documentation https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#resource:-person.

I'm unsure about the PHP syntax, but based on examples in https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client, try doing

```php
$custom_field_array = array();

...

$person->setUserDefined($custom_field_array);
```